# stalker beanstalkd, error with rails log file when loading rails env

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, beanstalkd

config/workers.rb

```
require File.expand_path("../config/environment", __FILE__)
```

when I run `stalk ./config/workers.rb` I get the following (notorious) error:

log/development.log

> Rails Error: Unable to access log
>   file. Please ensure that  exists and
>   is chmod 0666. The log level has been
>   raised to WARN and the output directed
>   to STDERR until the problem is fixed.

Notice that it cites the log file on top and inside the error message it does not cite the path... can someone explain this to me please?  I'm ready to rip some hair out...

Thanks!

Just to make sure, here is my ls -la... there are no user issues cuz i'm running it from my user in mac...

```
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 ericman  staff    0 Feb 10 19:11 development.log
```

Answer (score 0):

in your environments/development.rb (and production.rb before deploying) write explicitly

```
config.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log","worker_#{Rails.env}.log"))
```